# Are bumps on the inside of a cast iron drain pipe a sign of a problem?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, cast-iron

I'm replacing a toilet's wax ring in my 1960 US home. With the toilet removed, I noticed ugly-looking bumps on the inside of the cast iron drain pipe:

[image]

Here's a closer, more tasty look:

[image]

Aside from any [coprophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprophobia), are these bumps a sign of a serious problem (e.g. corrosion)?

Comment: You could make the effort and polish them out with a dremel...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm assuming the problem extends further than what I can see.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the standing water in horizontal waste water pipe. Looks like it is close to 1/2 full.

Comment: @SolarMike, you can't polish a turd ... lol ... i just could not help myself

Comment: @Charles It isn't half full, but it is standing water. As with the rest of my concerns, fixing it would mean replacing a substantial amount of very inaccessible pipe. So, time for the better part of valor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is signs of corrosion and in another 100-150 years, that will result in leaks in that pipe...

Comment: And it may last longer because sometimes the surface iron will corrode until a graphite flake is reached , then corrosion stops ( aka . graphitic corrosion ).